# Side balance of token in contract

Tags: solidity, erc-20, balances, assembly

Is it possible to have a "side balance" of an ERC20 token in the same contract? So when it's queryable with `token.balanceOf(address(this))`, for example, it doesn't appear until a certain instruction (aka function call) is made?

For example:

`Contract A` has a WETH balance of 100, and moves 25 WETH to this "side balance" within the same contract, so it'd be 75 WETH in-balance (queryable and transferrable through any of the typical ERC20 methods) and 25 WETH in this side balance.

So if you'd do `WETH.balanceOf(address(contractA))`, the output would be 75.

And if you'd like to move the 25 WETH back to the "main balance", you'd call the designated instruction like `contractA.moveToMain()`, and doing `WETH.balanceOf(address(contractA))` now would throw an output 100 WETH.

Is this possible in solidity and/or assembly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to have a "side balance" of an ERC20 token in the same contract.

If you need to have a "side balance", you can deploy another contract to use it as a "side balance". Use `transfer`, `transferFrom` methods to send and received the ERC20 tokens from the main contract to the "side balance" contract.

Comment: Having another contract is not an option in my case. Someone told me that it can be done through zk proofs, but that's all they mentioned. So I'm still wary on how a proof would invalidate part of a balance

Comment: Could be ETH balance as well, doesn't have to be ERC20 exclusively

Comment: Got it, but I'm not sure if zk proofs solve your problem.

Comment: Yea, no idea either. I started this post with the basis of being impossible what I want, but this dude told me this so might as well give it a shot and see if it can be done.